# Change theme on Samsung Galaxy Alpha

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, settings, themes, color

I have a Samsung Galaxy Alpha G850A and while I've been able to adjust a lot of settings including the wallpaper for the home screen, lock screen, etc I haven't figured out how to get rid of the ugly Windows 8 4 bit color scheme. Other phones apparently have access to a theme option under settings, mine shows nothing when I search in the settings for 'color' or 'theme' and I've probably have gone through 95% of the various settings *manually* at this point.

How do I change the theme colors on my Samsung Galaxy Alpha?

I am completely willing to hook it up to my PC and manually edit configuration files if someone is *that* awesome to know where it is (and if it supports RGBA)?

Comment: Is that color scheme affecting all your apps, or your home screen only?

Comment: @Izzy Most of the programs are blue/teal (phone, contacts, calculator, etc).

Comment: That's not what I've asked, John. I meant whether that 4-bit color scheme is affecting all apps, or if it's only present in your homescreen/launcher. In the latter case, an [alternative launcher](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher) might solve your issue.